Token-pasting operator ## in C preprocessor
Can I use the token-pasting operator ## in the following way:
#define NameIs 0xFFFF
#define PASTE NameIs
#define foo(text) My##text##Andrey

foo(PASTE);

...and don't get -> "MyPASTEAndrey"
getting the correct option -> "MyNameIsAndrey"
The problem is that the preprocessor doesn’t seem to understand that I want it to step one level deeper into the "paste," and I’m aware of this. Are there any clever workarounds for this?
Can I directly control the expansion or non-expansion of a macro?

https://godbolt.org/z/vxzPEo1sd
